# Android 12 - Launch MDM app after setup using PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL

Tags: android, mdm, device-owner, android-device-owner

We recently migrated our **Device Policy App(MDM)** to support **android 12** and would like to open our MDM dpc app after initial setup wizard is complete. This was working fine till android 11 until android 12 updates came out. We are handling **GET_PROVISIONING_MODE** and **ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE** but **PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL** is never called.

This is our code in Manifest for **PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL** :

```
<activity
        android:name=".pages.ProvisioningSuccessActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

We are calling `setResult(RESULT_FIRST_USER, intent);` on receive of **ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE**  intent.

Can anyone please help us with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Android 12 the `PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL` intent is **only** sent when

- Provisioning does not happen within the initial setup wizard (e.g. when the end-user installs and starts the DPC app which then triggers provisioning through `ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE`) or
- No activity for the `ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE` activity action can be resolved

See [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-12.0.0_r1:packages/apps/ManagedProvisioning/src/com/android/managedprovisioning/finalization/SendDpcBroadcastService.java;l=49;drc=11a31192f765c8086f769bfbc11365e1f58569b1;bpv=0;bpt=1) for the corresponding source code.

So in your case you have to replace the intent filter for `PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL` of your ProvisioningSuccessActivity with an intent filter for `ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE`.

**Background Information**

The `ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE` intent has already been introduced in Android 10, together with `GET_PROVISIONING_MODE`. Since then, it is the recommended intent for DPCs, to extend the initial setup wizard with a compliance screen and enforce initial policy settings:

> DPCs **must** use this new Intent instead of listening for the `ACTION_PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE` broadcast.
> [(source)](https://developer.android.com/work/versions/android-10#improved_provisioning_tools_for_work_profiles:%7E:text=Your%20DPC%20must%20use%20this%20new%20Intent%20instead%20of%20listening%20for%20the%20ACTION_PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE%20broadcast.).

Until Android 12 this change didn't affect existing DPC implementations, that only supported fully managed provisioning. DPCs that also wanted to make use of the new working profiles, already had to switch to the new intents with Android 10.

With the deprecation of [ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_DEVICE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_DEVICE), fully managed provisioning can now only be triggered by the setup wizard. DPC implementations that support only fully managed provisioning have to switch now also to the new intents.

The `ACTION_PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE` broadcast and the `PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL` intent are now only sent, when provisioning is triggered outside of the setup wizard. E.g. when a user installs and starts a  DPC app, which triggers provisioning of a working profile through [ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE).

Comment: Tnx . . . this helped . . finding the source documentation was a hassle . . if u dont mind, can may I know where u found the relevant documentation that guided you towards this answer ?

Comment: @PrinceChampappilly I started with a full-text search for `PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL` in the android open source code (see first link in my answer, for a starting point). To understand the history, the comments on the related commits were helpful and the following release notes for Android Enterprise:
https://developer.android.com/work/versions/android-10, https://developer.android.com/work/versions/android-11, https://developer.android.com/work/versions/android-12